# How to restore a degraded drive back into a zpool?

Tags: 18.04, server, zfs

I had an issue with my zpool - the dev id changed and one of the drives dropped out as degraded.

I've exported the pool and reimported using this command:

```
zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id zpool_primary
```

The status now appears as:

```
root@gomez:/home/nick# zpool status
pool: zpool_primary
state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices has been taken offline by the administrator.
        Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue functioning in a
        degraded state.
action: Online the device using 'zpool online' or replace the device with
        'zpool replace'.
scan: none requested
config:

        NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        zpool_primary               DEGRADED     0     0     0
          mirror-0                  DEGRADED     0     0     0
            wwn-0x5000cca27ec5c30d  ONLINE       0     0     0
            15142782844563214281    OFFLINE      0     0     0  was /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000cca252f6d327-part1
```

Viewing the list of disk ids:

```
root@gomez:/# ls /dev/disk/by-id
ata-SAMSUNG_HD204UI_S2HGJD1B503074           ata-WDC_WD80EZAZ-11TDBA0_1EGDNY2Z        ata-WDC_WD80EZAZ-11TDBA0_7SKWLU6W-part1  wwn-0x5000cca252f6d327-part9  wwn-0x5001b44f1aef7769
ata-SAMSUNG_HD204UI_S2HGJD1B503074-part1     ata-WDC_WD80EZAZ-11TDBA0_1EGDNY2Z-part1  ata-WDC_WD80EZAZ-11TDBA0_7SKWLU6W-part9  wwn-0x5000cca27ec5c30d        wwn-0x5001b44f1aef7769-part1
ata-SanDisk_SDSSDHII120G_154876410729        ata-WDC_WD80EZAZ-11TDBA0_1EGDNY2Z-part9  wwn-0x5000cca252f6d327                   wwn-0x5000cca27ec5c30d-part1  wwn-0x50024e9004e3d4f2
ata-SanDisk_SDSSDHII120G_154876410729-part1  ata-WDC_WD80EZAZ-11TDBA0_7SKWLU6W        wwn-0x5000cca252f6d327-part1             wwn-0x5000cca27ec5c30d-part9  wwn-0x50024e9004e3d4f2-part1
```

What is the easiest way to 'fix' the offline drive? It was previously degraded and I made it offline to do the export etc.

Can I do it by repeating the export / import process?  It wasn't clear when I imported again if I was supposed to specify the id of each drive to include. If that is the case, what would the command look like? I presume that the id I want to use is wwn-0x5000cca252f6d327 (i.e. without the 'part1' on the end)

Otherwise do I need to 'replace' the drive in the zpool and resilver?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by experimenting (since export and import are no-destructive).

Looking at blkid, I could see that both drives had the same UUID:

```
root@gomez:/dev/disk/by-uuid# blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="OS" UUID="e82b3fae-dce5-4b41-bd87-1f7bbd5f8039" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="5805358e-01"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="zpool_primary" UUID="9579775147971336578" UUID_SUB="6175940412684032547" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-efd142ee34d8cfea" PARTUUID="018883e2-0067-ac4b-8126-a2c02d0cfa45"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="CCTVPartition" UUID="6b35ec61-13aa-46f9-b6b7-dfd4b264318f" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="a31f929b-0989-4baa-8faf-082be6fca607"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="zpool_primary" UUID="9579775147971336578" UUID_SUB="15142782844563214281" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-693944edaab7d9e6" PARTUUID="91203b94-8387-1e4e-8646-5ba2cb6c461f"
/dev/sdb9: PARTUUID="e18a4bf7-b4c9-2149-bcd2-19ab9ba2182c"
/dev/sdd9: PARTUUID="009580ae-4c61-ab4d-a923-b7dc6ba14faa"
```

I therefore imported the drive using the UUID (and validate the import using zdb):

```
root@gomez:/dev/disk/by-id# zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-uuid/ zpool_primary
root@gomez:/dev/disk/by-id# zdb
zpool_primary:
    version: 5000
    name: 'zpool_primary'
    state: 0
    txg: 1160981
    pool_guid: 9579775147971336578
    errata: 0
    hostname: 'gomez'
    com.delphix:has_per_vdev_zaps
    vdev_children: 1
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'root'
        id: 0
        guid: 9579775147971336578
        children[0]:
            type: 'mirror'
            id: 0
            guid: 17679195099076183548
            metaslab_array: 256
            metaslab_shift: 36
            ashift: 12
            asize: 8001548713984
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 4
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 129
            children[0]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 0
                guid: 6175940412684032547
                path: '/dev/sdb1'
                whole_disk: 1
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 130
            children[1]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 1
                guid: 15142782844563214281
                path: '/dev/disk/by-uuid/9579775147971336578'
                whole_disk: 1
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 131
    features_for_read:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data
```

The pool was up and running, just with unusual identifiers:

```
root@gomez:/dev/disk/by-id# zpool status
  pool: zpool_primary
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an unrecoverable error.  An
        attempt was made to correct the error.  Applications are unaffected.
action: Determine if the device needs to be replaced, and clear the errors
        using 'zpool clear' or replace the device with 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-9P
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME                     STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        zpool_primary            ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0               ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdb                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            9579775147971336578  ONLINE       0     0     1
```

I then exported it again, and finally reimported using by-id:

```
root@gomez:/dev/disk/by-id# zpool export zpool_primary
root@gomez:/dev/disk/by-id# zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/ zpool_primary
root@gomez:/dev/disk/by-id# zpool status
  pool: zpool_primary
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        zpool_primary               ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x5000cca27ec5c30d  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x5000cca252f6d327  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Hopefully this helps someone else. I learnt the hard way about building raids and fstab etc with dev/sdx identifiers. Won't be making this mistake again.